# Error using variable from one form to another

Tags: php, forms, variables

In `PHP` I would like to use the `$num` value that is entered in the first form and execute a `pow()` function with `$num` and another variable, named `$rate`, which I enter in the second form.

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    Enter number: <input type="number" name="num" id="num"/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next"/><br>
</form>
<?php   if( isset($_POST['next']) ) : $num = $_POST['num']; ?>
        Entered number: <input type="text" name="entered" id="entered" value=" <?=$num ?> "/>
<?php   endif; ?>

<form action="" method="post">
    Enter rate: <input type="number" name="rate" id="rate"/>
    <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate"/>
</form>
<?php   if( isset($_POST['calculate']) ) : $rate = $_POST['rate'];
            if( $rate >=1 && $rate <=10 ) : echo pow($num, $rate); endif;
        endif;
?>
</body
```

When the code is executed it shows me:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: num in ... on line ...
0
```

What I need to add in the code to recognize the `$num` variable and execute right the `pow()`?

> **NB: Don't pay attention to the 'entered' input - it's just for a test.**

Comment: is that all in one file? how do you expect this to work? It seems you haven't understood how HTML Forms and PHP work together yet. Read some Beginners Tutorials.

Comment: Yes, it IS in one file and after all it DID work so the problem was not in my "beginner" understandings. I am writing here to seek for help from more experienced programmers than me so they will show me best solution of my problem and of course others that would face similar thing to go here and check it... sorry but don't appreciate some comments like yours that are softly said: useless and even offensive...

Comment: @user3572059 - you have two separate forms in your HTML. The first is used to generate `$num`. Have a look at your second form - where is `$num` used?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found yesterday and it works pretty well. Hope to be well understandable.

```
<?php   if( empty($_POST) ): ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    Enter number: <input type="number" name="num" id="num"/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next"/><br>
</form>
<?php   endif; ?>

<?php   if( isset($_POST['next']) ) : $num = $_POST['num']; ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    Entered number: <input type="text" name="entered" id="entered" value=" <?=$num ?> "/><br>
    Enter rate: <input type="number" name="rate" id="rate"/>
    <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate"/>
</form>
<?php   endif;

    if( isset($_POST['calculate']) ) : $rate = $_POST['rate'];
        $num = $_POST['entered']; 
        if( $rate >=1 && $rate <=10 ) : echo pow($num, $rate); 
        else: echo 'Enter rate between 1 and 10' . '<form> <input type="submit" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return TRUE;"> </form>';
        endif;
    endif;
?>
```